# Custom Open Graph meta tag image in vue

Tags: vue.js

In my app I have the functionality to share posts to facebook (by using the npm package/component vue-social-sharing)
I am interested to have our own custom logo as the image in Open Graph meta tags.
The Open graph meta tag works fine when I use an image from the internet but when I use a custom picture that I uploaded to
Flickr or imgur, link the meta property og:image to it and run `npm run build` I get the following error:

```
Error: Parse Error: <meta property="og:image" content="https://imgur.com/a/iOqpnAv"/ >
```

In my index.html file I have the following image which works and doesn't get an error.

```
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.snut.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-de-nature-9.jpg" />
```

but when I change it to my custom image then I get the specified error.

```
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://imgur.com/a/iOqpnAv"/ >
```

**Question** 
What do I need to do to link my custom image to the Open Graph meta tag image?
Is it my image from flickr or imgur that is the problem?
If so, why doesn't the link work?